# Creating an add-in installer for Excel from dll files

Tags: c#, excel

I created my Excel add-in using C # and Visual Studio. But how can I install it on another pc? There are only dll files in the release folder. How can I convert them to an installer or other file?

Am I missing something? Perhaps somewhere in the visual studio itself there is an opportunity to create an installer or another file that Excel can install.

[Release Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnAuH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First option:**

If the issue is only to deploy files to a specific location in another PC,
I think that the option of **"Inno-Setup"** installer will be helpful to you.

https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

1. Completely free for use
2. Very intuitive
3. An existing wizard for creating an installer from scratch

**Much easier option:**
Use winrar Self extracting archive:[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5aj6.png)

It will allow the user to select installation location and deploy files.